# scikit-learn: transformer to select columns by name

Tags: python, scikit-learn

### Context

I am working with scikit-learn and seeking for a transformer that allows me to simply select which columns to keep or which columns to drop.

### Problem

In practice, I would like to include in my pipeline an **additional** transformer step that allows me to choose which columns to keep or which to drop. I am aware that in below example I could simply use the remainder but that would not work in my real implementation where I need to parametrize column selection in order to easily apply it to both train, test and eventually scoring.

### Example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn import preprocessing
prep_pipeline = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("std_num", preprocessing.StandardScaler(), ["a", "b"])],
                                  remainder = "passthrough")
X = pd.DataFrame([[0., 1., 2., 2.],
              [1., 1., 0., 1.]])
X.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
prep_pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```

### Expected solution

The solution I need pipe an **additional** transformer step which role is exclusively to selected column ["a", "d"] therefore the expected output is:

```
array([[-1.,  1.],
       [ 1., -1.]])
```

Comment: you can write your transformer by defining a class which extends from BaseEstimator and TransformerMixin and overwrite fit and transform method to do you custom transformation

Answer (score 6):

I think you should use Pipeline of sklearn and following class in that Pipeline(current StandardScaler not support scaling parts of data frame)

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class DropSomeColumns(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, cols):
        if not isinstance(cols, list):
            self.cols = [cols]
        else:
            self.cols = cols

    def fit(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.Series):
        # there is nothing to fit
        return self

    def transform(self, X:pd.DataFrame):
        X = X.copy()
        return X[self.cols]
```

Comment: thank you. import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn import preprocessing
prep_pipeline = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("std_num", preprocessing.StandardScaler(), ["a", "b"]),
                                                ("dropcolumns", DropSomeColumns(), ["b", "c"] )],
                                  remainder = "passthrough")
X = pd.DataFrame([[0., 1., 2., 2.],
              [1., 1., 0., 1.]])
X.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
prep_pipeline.fit_transform(X) gives __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cols'

Comment: @Seymour I guess you can't achieve your desire by using ColumnTransformer - you can't use sklearn Pipeline class instead?

Comment: I do not have constraint in that sense. I can use Pipeline I guess, how can I achieve that using Pipeline and what is the main difference between ColumnTransformer and Pipeline?

Comment: from the documentation and source code, I can say ColumnTransformer take your data frame and independently apply some transformation on it (i.e. current transformation not affected by  former transformations - if I'm wrong please correct me) then concatenate the result . but in Pipeline each transformation affect latter ones

Comment: This approach works, but can be risky. If the dataframe has mixed types, if you supply the variable `list` as a `set`, or you want to use it with both dataframes and numpy arrays, you may get strange error messages.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I like is to use a ColumnTransformer that use `remainder='drop'` and a `passthrough` transformer in it.

By using the built in sklearn classes and not creating one of your own, you get a lot of nice data validation etc done right.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.pipeline
import sklearn.preprocessing
import sklearn.compose
X = pd.DataFrame([[0., 1., 2., 2.],
                  [1., 1., 0., 1.]])
X.columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
prep_step = sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ("std_num", sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler(), ["a", "b"])
],remainder = "passthrough")

# the first step - the StandardScaler - transforms the data from dataframe to numpy array, so we cannot index by ["a","d"]
# so use a get_indexer to index the np.array
pick_step = sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
    ('pick_cols','passthrough',X.columns.get_indexer(["a","d"]))
],remainder='drop')

prep_pipeline = sklearn.pipeline.make_pipeline( prep_step, pick_step)
prep_pipeline.fit_transform(X)
```

Final remark: the test output you specified seems wrong. I get

```
array([[-1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

with above code, and that seems right.